# Syntax highlighting not working in MD files for Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

The syntax highlighter does not seem to be working in Jekyll using the kramdown parser and rouge gem.  Quotes also do not show up highlighted and formatted.

Markdown file:

````
```javascript
function order(words){
  var array = words.split(' ');
  var result = array.slice();

  for (word in array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array[word].length; i++) {
       if (!isNaN(array[word][i])) {
         result[array[word][i] - 1] = array[word]
       }
     }
   }return result.join(' ');  
}
```
````

My config file listed below.

config.yml:

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
theme: minima
gems:
  - jekyll-feed

include: ['_pages']
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - vendor
#sass
sass:
  style: compressed
```

Comment: the md file and the config looks good. it sames that the issue is with the CSS, either it's not correctly  defined or not loaded. if your them use `site.baseurl` start there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Markdown file syntax is fine, you don't need to change it (check my comment bellow)

To get the code highlighting working, you need to check 2 things:

1. the *highlighter* and the *markdown processors* are correctly configured in `_config.yml`
2. the generated html files have access to a CSS highlighting-syntax style rules

## 1. Highlighter and the markdown processors configuration

As of jekyll 3.0, Kramdown as the Markdown engine, and Rouge as the syntax highlighter. are the [default jekyll setting](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/), and the only setting supported by [github pages](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0).

So you can remove their related setting, or set it explicitly at  `_config.yml` as follows:

```
# Conversion
markdown:    kramdown
highlighter: rouge

# Markdown Processors
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  auto_ids: true
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

## 2. Code highlighting style:

the generated html file **should have access** to a CSS code-highlighting rules, that depends on the theme that you're working with.

One way to do so, is to have a code-highlighting style rules defined in the main css file, then include that file in the html head of the *default layout*.

### define the CSS code-highliting rules

Make sure that the main CSS file, (located at `/assets/css`, and usually named `main.scss` or `style.scss`) has some code highlight CSS rules defined, either explicitly defined there, or by importing a file (scss, sass, or less) that contains the CSS rules.

for a quick check, I've putted some scss code-highlighting themes in this [repo](https://github.com/yaitloutou/sass-code-highlight)

- clone [sass-code-highlight](https://github.com/yaitloutou/sass-code-highlight) repo
- put `sass-code-highlight` folder inside  the sass directory (by default: `_sass`)
- inport the code-highlight to the main css file

in `assets/css/main.scss` add the following:

```
    @import "sass-code-highlight/monokai"; // 'monokai' as example
```

### include the Main CSS in the HTML HEAD

you need to have the sinppet bellow in the default layout (`_layouts/default.html`)

```
<head>
  <!-- head stuff-->

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/css/main.css"> <!-- IMPORTANT -->
</head>
```

either directly, or by including a `head.html`file - located at `_includes` directory - into it, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  {% include head.html %} <!--  <- include the head -->
  <body>
  {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note**: make sure that the `css path` is valid.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/yaitloutou/yaitloutou.github.io/blob/dae1bca4f100bd0cb2a7e18e2296796fd6fb81f4/_posts/2017-01-22-jekyll-code-highlighting.md) is an .md file with the same content, and this is its [output](https://yaitloutou.github.io/blog/2017/01/22/jekyll-code-highlighting/)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using *kramdown* then you need to use `~~~` to make it highlight the [code block](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#code-blocks) samples:

In this case:

```
~~~ javascript
function order(words){
   var array = words.split(' ');
   var result = array.slice(); 
   for (word in array) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < array[word].length; i++) { 
         if (!isNaN(array[word][i])) {
             result[array[word][i] - 1] = array[word] } 
                } 
    }return result.join(' '); 
 }
~~~
```

Anoche approach using IALs:

```
~~~
//Code
~~~ 
{: .language-javascript}
```

Comment: tried using ~~~ to no avail. Still not highlighting.

Comment: @NormanChan updated the question with another approach. Try also the former one leaving a space between the tiles and language name: ~~~ javascript

Comment: no, that did not work as well.  Perhaps my css files need to be modified?

Comment: Configuration is right, debug if the code is being generated with the right class highlighter and that the class is present in css.

Comment: the classes 'language-javascript' are being generated as well as 'highlighter-rouge'.

Comment: @NormanChan then there is some problem loading the css file, is it a public repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap the code in `{%highlight javascript%}... {%endhighlight%}` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Fenced code block works only with `Kramdown::kramdown` (use `~~~`) and `Kramdown::GFM` (use `~~~` or backticks) parsers ([see kramdown doc](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/gfm.html)).

If you want to use them, you can set kramdown parser in **_config.yml** :

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```