# Syntax highlighting not working for Julia in Jekyll website

Tags: markdown, jekyll, julia, syntax-highlighting, github-pages

I'm using Jekyll with Github Pages and I'm having trouble displaying Julia code with proper syntax highlighting on my website.

Here is my blog post:

```
---
layout: post
title: 'Example post'
---

Here the highlighting works:

{% highlight python %}
# Python
x = 9

for i in range(1, 11):
    y = sqrt(x) - i
    print(y)
{% endhighlight %}

Here it doesn't:

{% highlight julia %}
# Julia 
x = 9

for i = 1:10
    y = sqrt(x) - i
    println(y)
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

Which when I run Jekyll locally with `bundle exec jekyll serve --drafts` produces the following (screenshot):

[image]

I [read](https://haisum.github.io/2014/11/07/jekyll-pygments-supported-highlighters/) that Julia should be supported, so I'm not sure what might have gone wrong.

My `config_yml` looks something like this:

```
# Permalinks
permalink: pretty

# Setup
title: MyTitle
url: http://mywebsite.github.io
description: "Hello, I'm me."
paginate: 4
baseurl: ""

# Assets
# We specify the directory for Jekyll so we can use @imports.
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: :compressed

# About/contact
author:
  name: Firstname Surname
  email: hi@me.com

# Custom vars
version: 2.0.0
github:
  repo: https://github.com/poole/poole

# Gems
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-gist

pages_list:       
  FistPage: '/FirstPage'
  SecondPage: '/SecondPage'

encoding: utf-8

# Choose Markdown version
markdown: kramdown
```

Any ideas of how I might get this to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your link showing that Julia is supported is out of date. Starting with version 3 [Jekyll uses Rouge for highlighting](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting), not Pygments. But [Julia should be supported by Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers) anyway. Have you tried pushing to GitHub to see if it works there? What versions of Jekyll and Rouge do you have locally?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773267/syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-md-files-for-jekyll/41798467#41798467) where  I explain how to get the highlight working for jekyll in a general way. I think you can adapt it to your case.

Comment: When I push to Github then it indeed builds correctly and Julia also has correct syntax highlighting. I'm using Jekyll 3.0.3 and I couldn't figure out how to check the Rouge version. I suspect that something with my local ruby+ jekyll + gems + bundler installation might not be correct.

Comment: I think that already Chris answered, but if you still need help mention my name in a comment so I get a notification @ulima2_

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your local gems need to be updated. The latest release of Jekyll [is currently 3.4.0](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases).

As [described in their documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#already-have-jekyll) you can update Jekyll by running

```
gem update jekyll
```

Try running

```
gem oudated
```

to see if Rouge (and other gems) also need updating.

Comment: I used both commands and also `gem update` to just update them all, but the problem remains.

Comment: @ulima2_, how did you install Jekyll? What OS are you on?

Comment: OS X 10.11.6. I'm not familiar with Ruby, I just use all of this to manage my website. I first installed Jekyll and the related software such as bundler and gems last April. I went through the Github and Jekyll tutorial to install it and it worked out just fine. I remember having some trouble with Jekyll a couple of months ago (I think I updated my OS then) and googled around for a solution. I used some command line magic I found on Stackoverflow I think and things worked just fine again. So now I'm not entirely sure how and where things are installed.

Comment: I should add that I get the exact same problem (no Julia syntax highlighting) when I build the site locally with Jekyll on my Windows 7 machine. @yaitloutou any ideas?

Comment: @ulima2_, please run `gem list` and see what versions of Jekyll and Rouge you now have installed.

Comment: This gives: `jekyll (3.4.0, 3.3.1, 3.0.3)` and `rouge (2.0.7, 1.11.1, 1.10.1)`

Comment: You have multiple versions of both Jekyll and Rouge installed. Let's make sure your command-line `jekyll` is the right one. What does `jekyll --version` give now that you've updated your gems?

Comment: `jekyll --version` throws an error: `WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset: jekyll-watch (~> 1.1) rouge (~> 1.7) WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:40:in block in setup: You have already activated json 2.0.3, but your Gemfile requires json 1.8.6. Prepending bundle exec to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError) from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:228:in each .......`. But when I run `bundle exec jekyll --version` it returns `jekyll 3.3.1`.

Comment: @ulima2_, we're getting to the periphery of what I can help with. I'm not an OSX user, nor a Ruby power user. do you have a `Gemfile` in your project directory? I'm tempted to tell you to remove Ruby and all libraries (including Jekyll and Rouge) completely and reinstall them system-wide…

Comment: OK no worries. I mean as long as Julia highlighting works on Github, I'm alright. If I figure out what's wrong I'll post it here as an answer. @Chris: Thank you very much for your answers!

Yes I have a Gemfile, it contains `source 'https://rubygems.org' gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins`.